# Locking game data when update and render

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am doing a node.js game, and my my client data update / render logic is implemented like this :

```
   var rendering = false;
   var waiting_for_data = true;
   var data_update = false;

  socket.on('update', function(data){

      if(rendering)console.log("rendering");

      data_update = true;
      game_data = data;
      data_update = false;

      if(waiting_for_data){
        waiting_for_data = false;
        render();
      }


    });

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
          return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
                  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                  window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
                  window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
                  function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                  };
    })();


    function render(){


      while(data_update){
        console.log("waiting" + data_update);
      }

      if(game_data == null )console.log(game_data);

      rendering = true;
        //mapa.draw(context, game_data.player_position);
        renderer.draw(game_data);
      rendering = false;

      window.requestAnimFrame(render);
    }

  }
```

And I can see screen blinking with random position of my elements every few second. When i console.log data and object position they looks fine. Should i use some kind of locks or something else ? Is my rendering var and data_update var are enaught  secure fo updating data. One more thing, server is emiting 'update' 60 times per second.

Comment: Is it your intention to start a new renderer on every socket update. The render function once started will continue because of the `requestAnimFrame`, On the next socket update you call render again and start another render. Now you have two running, and you will add another each update.. Also the `while(data_update)` will block the whole page if render is ever called with `data_upodate = true` and setting it to true the false aground the `game_data` is not required. Javascript is single threaded, no need to lock as you will never have concurrent access conflicts.

Comment: Yes this is my intention, and when i render in io 'update' callback every thing is rendering fine, but i  have some small lags every few seconds with one client socket conected and few object on the screen. So i decided to try uisng requestAnimFram because i've readed that this is good for rendering preformance. I know that the problem is caused by something else but i still don't know why i have this weird behaviour like game_data become null every few seconds when i am using requestAnimFrame and i am just curious now

Answer (score 0):

You code looks like you are trying to be thread safe. There is no need.

JavaScript is single threaded. It only ever runs one instruction at a time. It only ever runs one function at a time. That function can not be interrupted, no other event, no other data will be changed until the current function is complete. Javascript is the ultimate in thread safe by virtue of the fact the it is sequential execution only. It can not be interrupted while executing code. All events like socket.on and requestAnimationFrame must wait for current execution to finish before they can run.

```
   // var rendering = false; // not needed
   var waiting_for_data = true;
   // var data_update = false; // not needed

   socket.on('update', function (data) {
       // this will never run if render is running
       //data_update = true; // nothing will see this
       game_data = data;  // ONLY this will ever happen between the line above and below
       // data_update = false; // nothing will see this

       if (waiting_for_data) {
           waiting_for_data = false;
           render();
       }

   });


   function render() {
       // if data_updata is true
       // then the while loop will have no way to exit and nothing 
       // can change data_update while this loop is running except some code in the loop
       // JavaScript is single threaded and can only do one thing at a time.
       //while (data_update) {
       //    console.log("waiting" + data_update);
       //}

       // again single thread. Only code in this function can run NOTHING else
       // can do anything until this function has exited all the way out
       //rendering = true;  
       renderer.draw(game_data);
       //rendering = false;

       requestAnimationFrame(render);
   }
```